# Проблема с return в методе java

Tags: java, функции, методы, return

У меня написано три return в условии, но IDEA просит указать return после условия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что компилятор допускает тот факт, что ни в одно условие может не зайти (ну например если `food` будет "ЖРАТВА") и тогда из метода надо что-то вернуть, а там дырка от бублика